# Unable to increase the region of interest of an image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to increase the region of interest of an image using the below algorithm.

> First, the set of pixels of the exterior border of the ROI is de termined, i.e., pixels that are outside the ROI and are neighbors (using four-neighborhood) to pixels inside it. Then, each pixel value of this set is replaced with the mean value of its neighbors (this time using eight-neighborhood) inside the ROI. Finally, the ROI is expanded by inclusion of this altered set of pixels. This process is repeated and can be seen as artificially increasing the ROI.

[image]

The pseudocode is below -

```
while there are border pixels:
    border_pixels = []

    # find the border pixels
    for each pixel p=(i, j) in image
        if p is not in ROI and ((i+1, j) in ROI or (i-1, j) in ROI or (i, j+1) in ROI or (i, j-1) in ROI) or (i-1,j-1) in ROI or (i+1,j+1) in ROI):
            add p to border_pixels

    # calculate the averages
    for each pixel p in border_pixels:
        color_sum = 0
        count = 0
        for each pixel n in 8-neighborhood of p:
            if n in ROI:
                color_sum += color(n)
                count += 1
        color(p) = color_sum / count

    # update the ROI
    for each pixel p=(i, j) in border_pixels:
        set p to be in ROI
```

Below is my code

```
    img = io.imread(path_dir)
    newimg = np.zeros((584, 565,3))
    mask = img == 0
    while(1):
        border_pixels = []
        for i in range(img.shape[0]):
            for j in range(img.shape[1]):
               for k in range(0,3):
                if(i+1<=583 and j+1<=564 and i-1>=0 and j-1>=0):
                    if ((mask[i][j][k]) and ((mask[i+1][j][k]== False) or (mask[i-1][j][k]==False) or (mask[i][j+1][k]==False) or (mask[i][j-1][k]==False) or (mask[i-1][j-1][k] == False) or(mask[i+1][j+1][k]==False))):
                        border_pixels.append([i,j,k])

         if len(border_pixels) == 0:
             break

        for (each_i,each_j,each_k) in border_pixels:
            color_sum = 0
            count = 0
            eight_neighbourhood = [[each_i-1,each_j],[each_i+1,each_j],[each_i,each_j-1],[each_i,each_j+1],[each_i-1,each_j-1],[each_i-1,each_j+1],[each_i+1,each_j-1],[each_i+1,each_j+1]]
            for pix_i,pix_j in eight_neighbourhood:
                if (mask[pix_i][pix_j][each_k] == False):
                    color_sum+=img[pix_i,pix_j,each_k]
                    count+=1
            print(color_sum//count)
            img[each_i][each_j][each_k]=(color_sum//count)

        for (i,j,k) in border_pixels:
            mask[i,j,k] = False
            border_pixels.remove([i,j,k])

    io.imsave("tryout6.png",img)
```

But it is not doing any change in the image.I am getting the same image as before 
so I tried plotting the border pixel on a black image of the same dimension for the first iteration and I am getting the below result-
[image]

I really don't have any idea where I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that I think works as you have requested (although I agree with @Peter Boone that it will take a while). My implementation has a triple loop, but maybe someone else can make it faster!

First, read in the image. With my method, the pixel values are floats between 0 and 1 (rather than integers between 0 and 255).

```
import urllib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import  binary_dilation, binary_erosion, disk
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu

# create a file-like object from the url
f = urllib.request.urlopen("https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXxJM.png")

# read the image file in a numpy array
# note that all pixel values are between 0 and 1 in this image
a = plt.imread(f)
```

Second, add some padding around the edges, and threshold the image. I used Otsu's method, but @Peter Boone's answer works well, too.

```
# add black padding around image 100 px wide
a = np.pad(a, ((100,100), (100,100), (0,0)), mode = "constant")

# convert to greyscale and perform Otsu's thresholding
grayscale = rgb2gray(a)
global_thresh = threshold_otsu(grayscale)
binary_global1 = grayscale > global_thresh

# define number of pixels to expand the image
num_px_to_expand = 50
```

The image, `binary_global1` is a mask that looks like this:

[image: bw mask]

Since the image is three channels (RGB), I process the channels separately. I noticed that I needed to erode the image by ~5 px because the outside of the image has some unusual colors and patterns.

```
# process each channel (RGB) separately
for channel in range(a.shape[2]):

    # select a single channel
    one_channel = a[:, :, channel]

    # reset binary_global for the each channel
    binary_global = binary_global1.copy()

    # erode by 5 px to get rid of unusual edges from original image
    binary_global = binary_erosion(binary_global, disk(5))

    # turn everything less than the threshold to 0
    one_channel = one_channel * binary_global

    # update pixels one at a time
    for jj in range(num_px_to_expand):

        # get 1 px ring of to update
        px_to_update = np.logical_xor(binary_dilation(binary_global, disk(1)), 
                                      binary_global)

        # update those pixels with the average of their neighborhood
        x, y = np.where(px_to_update == 1)

        for x, y in zip(x,y):
            # make 3 x 3 px slices
            slices = np.s_[(x-1):(x+2), (y-1):(y+2)]

            # update a single pixel
            one_channel[x, y] = (np.sum(one_channel[slices]*
                                             binary_global[slices]) / 
                                       np.sum(binary_global[slices]))      


        # update original image
        a[:,:, channel] = one_channel

        # increase binary_global by 1 px dilation
        binary_global = binary_dilation(binary_global, disk(1))
```

When I plot the output, I get something like this:

```
# plot image
plt.figure(figsize=[10,10])
plt.imshow(a)
```

[image: final image]

Comment: Thank you for it, and apologies for accepting it late, I had gone to some other rabbit hole.

Comment: I have few doubts- I really couldn't understand the idea behind eroding it with `5 pixels` initially, I can see the difference without eroding and with eroding but I am not able to grasp it why it is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting idea. You're going to want to use masks and some form of [mean ranks](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.rank.html#mean-bilateral) to accomplish this. Going pixel by pixel will take you a while, instead you want to use different convolution filters.

If you do something like this:

```
image = io.imread("roi.jpg")
mask = image[:,:,0] < 30
just_inside = binary_dilation(mask) ^ mask
image[~just_inside] = [0,0,0]
```

you will have a mask representing just the pixels inside of the ROI. I also set the pixels not in that area to 0,0,0.

Then you can get the pixels just outside of the roi:

```
just_outside = binary_erosion(mask) ^ mask
```

Then get the mean bilateral of each channel:

```
mean_blue = mean_bilateral(image[:,:,0], selem=square(3), s0=1, s1=255)
#etc...
```

This isn't exactly correct, but I think it should put you in the right direction. I would check out [image.sc](https://forum.image.sc/) if you have more general questions about image processing. Let me know if you need more help as this was more general direction than working code.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'll check it out definitely.

Comment: Could you help me in building this approach a bit more, I have the mask representing the pixels outside but I am not able to figure out how to approach further